# How to fix '`render` method found on the returned component instance' error in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

For some reason my React component is showing this error:

```
Warning: ReactComponent(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define 'render'.
```

Even though I have defined `render` in my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


export class Cart extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('cart', this.props.cart);
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
                <Component cartItem={this.props.cartItem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { cart: state.cart };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

What is wrong with my component that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line right here:

```
<Component cartItem={this.props.cartItem} />
```

Here `Component` is referring to `React.Component`, or `ReactComponent` you see in the error message which doesn't implement the `render` method, it's just the superclass for your components. You're trying to create an element of `Component` but that doesn't have a `render` method and makes no sense.

You may have used the wrong component, and forgot to import and use the correct component.